# Ubuntu show grub boot menu and do not auto boot?

Tags: grub2

I have the issue where every time I boot up my laptop it shows the boot menu and I have to choose that I want to use Ubuntu. I have searched the web and found that others have the same issue, however the solutions that has worked for them where they set the timer to 0 do not work for me.

What I have tried:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
```

Then i ran `sudo update-grub`.

I still have the issue. I run a fresh installation of Ubuntu 18.04.2.

This file looks like the following:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=countdown
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0.1
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Comment: is it dual boot or single?

Comment: It is singel boot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you tried:

```bash
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
```

Then run `sudo update-grub`

Does not work because grub automatically changes a time out of zero to 10. What you need to do is this:

```bash
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=0.1
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0.1
```

Then run `sudo update-grub`

Comment: This did not help, tried 1 as well.

Comment: @Jesper.Lindberg I added an additional option. If it still doesn't work please update your question with the entire contents of your `/etc/default/grub` file.

Comment: Did not help, I have updated my first post with the content of the file.

Comment: @Jesper.Lindberg I've added another option.