# Dual System: Can not get into GRUB interface automatically

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, bios, boot-repair

I am using a dual system, Windows/Ubuntu. I used to be able to get in GRUB automatically. However, after one rebooting from Windows to Ubuntu, I can not get into the GRUB interface unless I press "F11" to get into the boot device selection interface. And I select the ubuntu boot device and I can get into GRUB as before. I see the "windows boot manager" is the top priority now. Why is that? How could I solve this?

Comment: It is not clear if you are asking how to [restore GRUB appearing at every boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1156369/ubuntu-show-grub-boot-menu-and-do-not-auto-boot). or if you are asking how to [re-order the GRUB choices](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144464/reorder-grub-to-list-windows-on-top). Please limit questions to a single question.

Comment: What brand/model system? Some like HP, need UEFI update & even then you can only change boot order from within UEFI settings, f2 or whatever your key is. Most other systems support efibootmgr and changes using it including grub install work. You may also need BCD setting in Windows as some UEFI sync BCD with UEFI and that is issue. In Windows: `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite certain what you are asking, however, I think you might have already answered your own question. Windows boot manager is on the top of your boot options, and I am guessing you have fast boot ON, as such you directly get booted into Windows. Edit your boot options from the bios screen and move Ubuntu above Windows Boot Manager. That way you should always get the grub menu.

However if I'm misunderstanding something, please let me know. :)

Comment: Thank you.  Can you elaborate more about how to turn off the fast boot or "move Ubuntu above Windows Boot Manager"? I think it might be the reason but don't know how to do it.

Comment: To change your boot order, [this blog](https://www.it4nextgen.com/change-boot-order-uefi-bios/) might be helpful. Even though the BIOS options might differ depending on your system, the overall approach should remain the same.

To disable fastboot, check out [this blog](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-windows-10-fast-startup).