# GNU GRUB fast boot on bios and can’t access bios now

Tags: gnu-screen, system-call-fastboot

**OK so basically I have fast boot on and I went to Ubuntu Linux and  I have a windows and operating system and now because I had fast boot on no USB port works now because this one is in the GNU GRUB it doesn’t read the ports And I can’t do anything please help**

Comment: Check with the manufacturer of your computer and see if you can reset your BIOS to factory defaults.

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure about your exact question as it kind of vague. It might possibly be a duplicate of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1265257/dual-system-can-not-get-into-grub-interface-automatically)
.
However as far as I understand,

- You are unable to boot from USB or access the grub menu. Try pressing the `delete` button (may vary depending on the system) at the start of your boot sequence to access the BIOS menu. And move the boot order to move the windows boot priority down. [[1](https://www.it4nextgen.com/change-boot-order-uefi-bios/)]
- **Disabling fast boot**: Try this blog [[2](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-windows-10-fast-startup)] to disable fast boot from windows 10

If my understanding about your problem is wrong, please rephrase your question. [[3](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)]